# UV Unwraping, long face

Tags: texturing, uv

So i'm trying to recreate sombra from overwatch for a project but when i Unwrap her face, it comes out extremely long on the Z axis.

I've tried to add / remove multiple seams but it doesn't change anything.

Just wondering if you could help me.

[image]

Here are the seams :

[image]
[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: i sent it but idk if it worcked

Comment: Could be your mesh is scaled im object mode? Try to apply scale in object mode. CTRL-A -> Apply Scale. Afterwards you can unwrap again and it should work

Comment: wait, wdym by "apply scale" ?
is there a modifier scale ?

Comment: you need to copy paste the URL it will create once you've uploaded

Comment: wow it worked. ty very much moonboots